# Windows 10 file explorer files and folder icons are blank white icons

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I don't know what the heck happened but, my folder and file icons in windows 10 pro file explorer are now simply all BLANK doc ICONS covering the actual icons.

I've rebuilt the IconCache.db file several times and restarted several times.

I'm dumbfounded.

No, I haven't installed anything new.

Here's a screenshot of my file explorer.

[image]

Here's another image of my file explorer wit the problem.

[image]

Here's the image of my registry as requested:

[image]

Here's the image of my registry for icon overlays... every entry has the DEFAULT NAME with nothing else in any of the below folders

[image]

And finally shell folder overlays "HAS" something in it...hmmm.

[image]

Comment: Check out the Shell Icons registry key. Post the registry export or share the screenshot. [Shortcut Icons Covered with White Icons or Black Boxes [Icon Overlay](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-overlapping-icon-windows-7-vista/)

Comment: That isn't the problem, although thank you for this link.  29 doesn't exist under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons and therefore I never installed WINBUBBLE.  Also, I explored the second link in the article you sent me to. NO JOY there as well. I simply have the default KEY value NOT SET.

Comment: `29` is for shortcut overlay. For folders, the icon index is different. Can you post a screenshot of that key. Additionally, check (using Autoruns) if there are any [ShellIconOverlayIdentifier shell extensions](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/green-tick-or-blue-arrows-icon-overlay-displayed-for-files-in-windows-explorer/).

Comment: Have you tried to create a new user account to check?

Comment: No offense but I do not WANT to create a NEW account. I need a REAL SOLUTION, not a band-aid my friend.  There's GOT TO BE an answer and out of the 6 MIL+ developers across this great planet, it's had to have happened to someone else, right? REAL SOLUTIONS!

Comment: @PeterTheAngularDude Were you able to find any concrete solution? I am facing the same issue here, but with onedrive icons only: https://superuser.com/questions/1303588/windows-10-onedrive-files-and-folder-icons-are-blank-and-white

Answer (score -2):

This was solved LONG, LONG AGO with the CREATORS update.

All solved.

Comment: One can assume the author was using the Creators Update (1703) or the Fall Creators Update (1709) since this was submitted in November 2017.

Comment: And yet, curiously, this answer was posted *by the author of the original question.*

Comment: Yes I did and yes you are correct