# Windows 10 OneDrive files and folder icons are blank and white

Tags: windows-10, icons, onedrive

I think the problem I am facing is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1265609/windows-10-file-explorer-files-and-folder-icons-are-blank-white-icons?rq=1) link but I am only facing it for OneDrive files and folders. Instead of displaying the normal icons, mine are showing a blank white icon as shown here:

[image]

How can I get the normal icons back?

Comment: If the issue is only in OneDrive, have you drive finding and installing the latest OneDrive client? Or possibly uninstalling OneDrive and then reinstalling it? Also, is it just me or does it appear that a white page icon has been placed OVER the regular icons? This could indicate you have/had another application that tried to modify the OneDrive icons and may have failed.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for pointing out the idea about reinstalling onedrive. As windows 10 contains it already so I was trying to uninstall it firstly (which is not possible). Being a researcher I just started looking into the shell icons etc.

Comment: You can Uninstall OneDrive in Windows 10 1709. I believe one earlier version also allows this, but the removal was improved in 1709.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solution I found was just getting onedrive .exe file from Microsoft website, even if you have it already preinstalled on your Windows 10.

Install that file and restart your PC.

I'm glad the icons looks fine now.